# How to include Facebook PHP SDK v5 in codeigniter 2.x?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with new facebook sdk, I cant include this new sdk in codeigniter. On the previous version I just add

```
 base_facebook.php
 facebook.php
 fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
```

this 3 file in my libraries folder and its working fine. But now I want to use SDK v5. How can I do that ?

Comment: Use Composer, or the autoloader the SDK comes with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted#install-composer

Comment: I download it but how cat I use this in my controller ??

Answer (score 0):

[tried this tutorial](https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v3-x-to-v5#installation-with-composer)

sample controller

```
# controllers/foo.php

// If you haven't included the autoloader yet
//require(APPPATH.'third_party/facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php');
require(APPPATH.'third_party/fb_persistent_data_interface.php');

class Foo extends CI_Controller
{
  function bar()
  {
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      // Your app ID & secret config here
      // . . .
      'persistent_data_handler' => new CIFacebookPersistentDataHandler(),
      ]);
  }
}
```